# Javascript for Previous and Next Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-pagination

I am trying to write a function that will use a set of html pages named 1.html, 2.html, 3.html, 4.html, etc. with previous and next buttons on each page. Clicking a previous or next arrow button will take me to the next html page in my browser. So if I am on a page named "2.html" it will know that, and take me to "3.html"

I see a lot of pagination scripts, but this is much simpler. I want to actually go to another html page. I had some code like this, but it's not working like I would expect-- can anyone help...?

```js
  function nextPg(step) { 
      var str = window.location.href;
      if(pNum = str.match(/(\d+)\.html/i)){
        pNum = pNum[1] * 1 + step+'';
        if(pNum>0){
          pNum = "".substr(0, 4-pNum.length)+pNum;
          window.location = str.replace(/\d+\.html/i, pNum+'.html'); 
        }
      }
    } 

<a href="nextPg(+1)">Next Page &raquo;</a>
```

I tried @void's suggestion and edited the code like this, but still having trouble getting it to work to load my next page called 'page2.html'

```js
$( "#target" ).keyup(function( event ) {
  
    function newDoc(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    url = url.split('/').pop();
    curr = +curr.replace("page","").replace(".html","");
    window.location.href = "page"+ (curr+1) +".html";
    }
})
 
$( "#other").click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).keyup();
});
```

My button looks like this:

```js
<button id="other">LOAD ANOTHER PAGE</button>
```

Comment: why dont use cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to pick the easy way?

```
  function nextPg(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    url = url.split('/').pop();
    curr = +curr.replace("page","").replace(".html","");
    window.location.href = "page"+ (curr+1) +".html";
    }
```

Now bind it with the keyup event as you want.

Comment: That looks like much better code, and I tried it, but is there anything else I need to make it work ? How would I bind that with a keyup event ?